# How to import .py file to another file

Tags: python, django, python-2.7, python-3.x, pycharm

I have 2 `.py` files in 1 project and use pycharm IDE, I want to import one file to another, but when I use  " import "  `list.py` into `operation.py`, do not know this file and has error, how can I solve this issue which know my file?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In pycharm, you should press Ctrl+Space 2 times for see intellisense and then you see whole of your files and when you select one of them, it imports full its requirements.

Answer (score 2):

Have a read of the python docs on [modules](http://docs.python.org/tutorial/modules.html). This covers what you're attempting to do.